# Generate qrcodes and print as mailing labels in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, qr-code

I have a routine that generates qrcodes and stores them in a folder. What I needed was to print them as mailing labels in the crystal reports identifying the desired quantity of each one. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

```
 Sub GeraQRCode(valor As String)

    Dim options = New QrCodeEncodingOptions With {.DisableECI = True, .CharacterSet = "UTF-8", .Width = 250, .Height = 250}
    Dim writer = New BarcodeWriter()
    writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    writer.Options = options

    Dim qr = New BarcodeWriter()
    qr.Options = options
    qr.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    Dim result = New Bitmap(qr.Write(valor))
    result.Save(Server.MapPath("~\QRCode\" & Trim(valor) & ".png"))

End Sub
```